# Problems restricting access using Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I've set up XAMPP on a Windows 7 machine, and I want to restrict access to the htdocs folder to only requests from the local machine. C:\Xampp\htdocs is the web root folder.

I have the following in my apache/conf/httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>


<Directory "C:/Xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All

    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

All my .htaccess files are blank.

But when I navigate to the web root folder via a browser, I get the following message:

**Access forbidden!**

**You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.**

I tried adding the IP restrictions to the `<Directory>...</Directory>`, but it made no difference.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the IP address you are accessing the vhost with, and as this server is not currently serving you can easily check the access log to find your IP (XAMPP uses `%INSTALL_DIR%\apache\logs\access.log` by default).

The IP used to request a vhost is dependent on the IP returned to you by the DNS request. If you're not running a DNS server on your local network then I presume you've added an entry to your [hosts file](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/edit-hosts-file-in-windows-7-windows-vista/). Mine reads

```
127.0.0.1       localhost project1 project2 project3
```

and when I navigate to a project I've hosted locally, my IP appears as `127.0.0.1` in the `access.log`

Comment: I did the following: [1] Added the hosts entry as above; [2] Navigated to my web root (and got the same error); [3] Looked in the apache access.log file - this is what I saw: `zongo - - [02/Jan/2011:15:27:07 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 1174 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10"`; [4] Since it looked like the requests were coming from **zongo**, I added that to the `allow from` list in the `httpd.conf` file and saved it; [5] Restarted Apache; [6] Nav'd to the webroot, but got the same error.

Comment: OK, I changed `l27.0.0.1    localhost` to `127.0.0.1    localhost zongo`, and that's fixed the problem. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Glad you're up and running! Using a hostname is not very secure, although for your needs it may be sufficient. I'd recommend changing the logformat http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformatto see IPs and using an IP instead.

Comment: Just to clarify, Andy, are you saying that [1] it's not secure to use a hostname to restrict access, as I have done in httpd.conf, or [2] it's not secure to have a hostname logged in my access.log file?

Comment: It's preferable to have an IP in your access log (see logformat link) as it's easier to masquerade behind a hostname, and using a host to restrict access is less secure than an IP because the IP is more likely to be static (although that's not guaranteed either!)

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing the server using the `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` addresses. You will be using the ip address of the local machine - add that to your allow from directive. If your local machine IP address is 192.168.1.183 then you would use

```
allow from 192.168.1.183
```

Comment: I tried adding the ip address that I obtained from going to a site like whatsmyip.org, but that didn't work. I also tried the ip address I got when I pinged my machine name, but that didn't work either.

Comment: If you are behind nat, then whatsmyip.org won't help you. Open a command prompt and type 'ipconfig /all'. Then find the address of your network interface.

Comment: @Blueben, the IP address from ipconfig /all is the same IP address I got back from a ping. I have tried that, and it doesn't work.